# Invalid JSON in influxdb-php

Tags: php, influxdb

When a query is made, it retuns 404, invalid json error.

I use 8083 as port. Is there any another port for api.
Below is the code I use. Any help is welcome.

```
<?php
require '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new InfluxDB\Client('153.148.25.44', '8083');
    $database = $client->selectDB('Meters');
    $result = $database->getQueryBuilder()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('GDATA')
    ->limit(2)
    ->getResultSet()
    ->getPoints();

    //$result = $database->query('select * from  GDATAlimit  LIMIT 5;');
    //$points = $result->getPoints();
    //$lastQuery = $client->getLastQuery();

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Tested database connection, it is working.

Version is 0.13

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid JSON' in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\vendor\influxdb\influxdb-php\src\InfluxDB\ResultSet.php:30

Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\vendor\influxdb\influxdb-php\src\InfluxDB\Driver\Guzzle.php(100): InfluxDB\ResultSet->__construct('404 page not fo...')

#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\vendor\influxdb\influxdb-php\src\InfluxDB\Client.php(198): InfluxDB\Driver\Guzzle->query()

#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\vendor\influxdb\influxdb-php\src\InfluxDB\Database.php(78): InfluxDB\Client->query('Meters', 'SELECT * FROM "...', Array)

#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\vendor\influxdb\influxdb-php\src\InfluxDB\Query\Builder.php(261): InfluxDB\Database->query('SELECT * FROM "...')

#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\home.php(10): InfluxDB\Query\Builder->getResultSet()

#5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\vendor\influxdb\influxdb-php\src\InfluxDB\ResultSet.php on line 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API port for InfuxDB v0.13 is 8086. I was using 8083, which is used for web.